# Facebook SDK session provided in an unopened state

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, facebook-sdk-4.0

so I'm trying to refactor my app that uses the Facebook API to use fragments instead of activities. Before, after logging in with Facebook, I would get taken to a new activity - now, I'm trying to use fragments instead. However, ever since I started using fragments, it's been failing during requests, giving me an error "Session provided to a Request in un-opened state"

I added all the UIHelper lifecycle methods to my fragment, but I'm still getting the error. I basically copied the exact code that the example fragment uses, and I'm still getting this issue. Can anybody help me out? Here's my fragment, and the activity that sets it up (most of it is stock code taken directly from Facebook's example)

Fragment:

```
public class ConvoFragment extends Fragment {
String name;
ListView convos;
SwipeRefreshLayout rootView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    rootView = (SwipeRefreshLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.convos_fragment,
            container, false);

    convos = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.conversation_list);
    name = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("global", 0).getString("myName", "");

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    RequestAsyncTask req = new Request(session, "/me/inbox/", null, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback()
    {
        public void onCompleted(Response response)
        {
            final Response resp = response;
            try
            {
                if (response != null)
                {
                    GraphObject asdf2 = response.getGraphObject();
                    Log.i("graphobject", response.toString());
                    //This logs the Session Provided to Request in unopened state error. Everything below will fail

                    JSONObject obj = asdf2.getInnerJSONObject();

                    JSONArray threads= obj.getJSONArray("data");

                    final ConvoAdapter adapter = new ConvoAdapter(getActivity(), convertArray(threads), name);

                    convos.setAdapter(adapter);

                    setupRefreshListener();
                    setupItemListener(adapter);

                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).executeAsync();
    return rootView;
}
```

So it fails right as it makes the request, because the request essentially returns null. Here's my activity that sets up the fragments:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String USER_SKIPPED_LOGIN_KEY = "user_skipped_login";

private static final int SPLASH = 0;
public static final int FILE = 1;
public static final int CONVOS = 2;
public static final int SETTINGS = 3;
public static final int ABOUT = 4;
private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = ABOUT +1;

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

private Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[FRAGMENT_COUNT];
private boolean isResumed = false;
private boolean userSkippedLogin = false;
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        userSkippedLogin = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(USER_SKIPPED_LOGIN_KEY);
    }

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);

    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.chatstatssmall);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    MainFragment splashFragment = (MainFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.splashFragment);
    fragments[SPLASH] = splashFragment;
    fragments[FILE] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fileFragment);
    fragments[CONVOS] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.convoFragment);
    fragments[SETTINGS] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.userSettingsFragment);
    fragments[ABOUT] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.aboutFragment);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    for(int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
        transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar act = getSupportActionBar();
    act.setTitle("Welcome to ChatStats!");
    act.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.chatstatssmall);
    act.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            showFragment(SETTINGS, false);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public final static String extra_msg = "chatstats.passArray";

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
    isResumed = true;

    // Call the 'activateApp' method to log an app event for use in analytics and advertising reporting.  Do so in
    // the onResume methods of the primary Activities that an app may be launched into.
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
    isResumed = false;

    // Call the 'deactivateApp' method to log an app event for use in analytics and advertising
    // reporting.  Do so in the onPause methods of the primary Activities that an app may be launched into.
    AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putBoolean(USER_SKIPPED_LOGIN_KEY, userSkippedLogin);
}

@Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        // if the session is already open, try to show the selection fragment
        userSkippedLogin = false;
        showFragment(FILE, false);
    } else if (userSkippedLogin) {
        showFragment(FILE, false);
    } else {
        // otherwise present the splash screen and ask the user to login, unless the user explicitly skipped.
        showFragment(SPLASH, false);
    }
}

public void startMainActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (isResumed) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        int backStackSize = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < backStackSize; i++) {
            manager.popBackStack();
        }
        // check for the OPENED state instead of session.isOpened() since for the
        // OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED state, the selection fragment should already be showing.
        if (state.equals(SessionState.OPENED)) {
            showFragment(FILE, false);
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            showFragment(SPLASH, false);
        }
    }
}

public void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
        if (i == fragmentIndex) {
            transaction.show(fragments[i]);
        } else {
            transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
    }
    if (addToBackStack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

This uiHelper stuff is really confusing me. I'd appreciate if anybody could let me know what I might be doing wrong. I thought I followed the Facebook documentation (available here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.23.1/class/UiLifecycleHelper/ ) exactly, but I'm still getting this error.